# кнопка меняет расположение только один раз (по JFrame)

Tags: java

я хотел сделать игру где нужно угадать какая кнопка правильная, но при нажатии на одну из кнопок, меняют расположение все кнопки, но только один раз.
вот сам код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessGame implements MouseListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // int count = 0;

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setSize(200, 30);
        field.setLocation(200, 0);
        field.setEditable(false);
        field.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(500, 610);
        panel.setLocation(90, 60);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        final int locationX = rnd.nextInt(panel.getWidth());
        final int locationY = rnd.nextInt(panel.getHeight());

        final int locationX2 = rnd.nextInt(panel.getWidth());
        final int locationY2 = rnd.nextInt(panel.getHeight());

        JButton button2 = new JButton("УГАДАЙ");
        button2.setSize(150, 90);
        button2.setFocusable(false);
        button2.setLocation(400, 100);
        button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        JButton button = new JButton("УГАДАЙ");
        button.setSize(150, 90);
        button.setFocusable(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.gray);
        button.setLocation(100, 100);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == button) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "вы не угадали!", "проигрыш!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
                   
                    button2.setLocation(locationX2, locationY2);
                    button.setLocation(locationX, locationY);
                    

                }
            }
        });

        button2.setBackground(Color.gray);
        button2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == button2) {
                    
                    button2.setLocation(locationX2, locationY2);
                    button.setLocation(locationX, locationY);                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "вы угадали!", "успех!", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

                }

            }

        });
        button2.setVisible(true);

        button.setVisible(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUESS GAME");
        frame.setSize(700, 800);
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(field);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: у Вас рандомное распололожение кнопки определяется всего один раз, а должно определяться при каждом клике на кнопку: `button2.setLocation(rnd.nextInt(panel.getWidth()), rnd.nextInt(panel.getHeight()));` и т.д.

Comment: спасибо MrFylypenko